# Parsing command line with jCommander from Groovy (sample code fails)

Tags: groovy, command-line-interface, jcommander

I'm trying to use jCommander to parse command line parameters in Groovy.

*(MacBook (El Capitan), Groovy 2.4.11, jCommander-1.49 )*

The example provided on jCommander.org (see http://jcommander.org/#_groovy) reads:

```
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;

public class Args {
  @Parameter
  private List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

  @Parameter(names = { "-log", "-verbose" }, description = "Level of verbosity")
  private Integer verbose = 1;

  @Parameter(names = "-groups", description = "Comma-separated list of group names to be run")
  private String groups;

  @Parameter(names = "-debug", description = "Debug mode")
  private boolean debug = false;
}
```

but when I try to run that code (*groovy jCommanderSample.groovy*) I get:

```
lexu@mbp:~/.../Groovy/CliParameters $ groovy jCommanderSample.groovy
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.newBuilder() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.newBuilder() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at jCommanderSample$_run_closure1.doCall(jCommanderSample.groovy:9)
    at jCommanderSample.run(jCommanderSample.groovy:8)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: lexu, have you got chance to try the solution?

Comment: thx Rao. Your solution helped me understand what is going wrong .. the code provided cannot run standalone, it still requires a caller .. I'll be adding a simple working script, that can be run from the command line and demonstrates parameter handling ..

Comment: Did not get it from your response. Is the original issue posted in the question resolved?

Comment: Yes and no .. the snippet, as provided on the jCommander webpage doesn't compile, and once I applied your fix, it did not demonstrate (to me) how to use the code.  That's why I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I copied to my snippets collection:

Sample Groovy Script for jCommander

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import com.beust.jcommander.*
class Simple {
  static class Args {
    @Parameter
    private List<String> aParamList = [];
    @Parameter(names = [ "--quiet", "-q" ], description = "quiet mode, no output to STDOUT")
    private Boolean aQuiet = false;

    @Parameter(names = [ "--logging", "-l" ], description = "logging verbosity (0-4)")
    private Integer aLogLevel = 1;

    @Parameter(names = [ "--group", "-g" ], description = "group name, default is 'none'")
    private String aGroupName = 'none';
  }

  public static main(String[] pArgs) {
    Boolean vQuiet    ;
    Integer vLogLevel ;
    String vGroupName ;
    List<String> vParamList;
    new Args().with {
      try {
        new JCommander(it, pArgs)
        vQuiet     = it.aQuiet;
        vLogLevel  = it.aLogLevel;
        vGroupName = it.aGroupName;
        vParamList = it.aParamList;
      }
      catch(com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException e) {
        println "Fatal Error parsing arguments:  $e.message"
        System.exit(-1)
      }
    }
    println "unbound parameters: " + vParamList;
    println "          LogLevel: $vLogLevel";
    println "       Silent Mode: $vQuiet";
    println "         GroupName: $vGroupName";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might aware that there is a difference in list definition in `groovy`.
In java, `{ ..}` is used. In groovy as below:

```
def list = [1, 2]
```

Change from:

```
@Parameter(names = { "-log", "-verbose" }, description = "Level of verbosity")
```

To:

```
@Parameter(names = ["-log", "-verbose" ] , description = "Level of verbosity")
```

Comment: +1 now the code compiles (almost), but the compiler now complains about the missing main method .. see my own answer for a working 'demo' version for jCommander